# ios - Best way to create own level editor

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, multi-level

I've created a core mechanic of my game and want to create a level editor for it. my game is not a tile-based one, so my needs are quite specific. Game is written using Swift and Cocos2d-swift, but i dont think i can figure something out with Sprite Builder.

What you can advice me? Can I for example create a level editor with c# and then use it from swift code?

And what data structure is the best? 
I mean is it possible to serialize classes on desktop Swift application and then just load them on ios from file or I'll need to use json/xml?

Comment: Do you want users to be able to edit, or is it just for your team ?

Comment: @Antzi it is for me by now. I'd die creating levels programmatically. maybe when the game will be popular (lol) i'll release it in public

Comment: what prevents you from using sb? maybe if you could post your requirements here or on spritebuilder.com i can give you some advice. templating (sub file nodes) are very powerful.don't reinvent the wheel unless you can make a better wheel or a more specialized one

Answer (score 1):

It might be an old question but I ended up with using a .Net powered solution. I choosed as It has all controls that you need for creating a rich user interface and also, it has a lot of built-in and third party solutions for serializing levels in any way you want. And the c# syntax is very similar to the Swift one.

The only problem is that you might run windows to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

My game in development also needed a non-tile level editor. A few months ago I took some time to make my choice.

Since my project still uses cocos2d 2.x, I don't use the whole new 3.x and SB system. After some investigation I found out that it would be too time consuming to adjust my whole project to the new system and adjusting SB to my needs, mainly because my game engine has been in development for quite some time and is close to finished. Further more, I couldn't find the right information to actually make it work for my game (it needed some odd level architecture I guess).
Finally, I didn't find any other good alternative so I decided to create my own level editor. In this way I had full control and I knew exactly how everything worked which was a huge advantage for me.

Right now my level editor has been finished for some time and works like a charm. I still think in my situation I made the right choice. Also because I learned a lot this way, building everything from the ground up. Having said that, for my next game I will probably go with the main stream and use SB from the start. Also for you I advice you to still check out SB and take some time for it before making an alternative choice...

I'll explain how I did mine. Disclaimer: it has some oddity's which only worked in my situation, but hopefully it helps a bit with choosing your own way to go, that's the goal I'm aiming at...

---

I used:

**max/msp**
Although it's developed to make music and audio based software, I used max/msp because it's very easy and fast for creating visual and interface based software as well.
More importend: I happened to be very experienced in it, which shortened the development time tremendously.

**javascript**
Inside the max/msp patch is a javascript file running. This file is like a bridge between the interface and the visual representation of the level being edited, and the database in which the level
is saved in. 70% of the editor development went into this file I think.

**sqlite**
All the data is written in a sqlite database. Again, this has been mainly the choice because it saved a great amount of development time in my case. I could have used xml files for instance, but my game was already using a sqlite database and because of this I felt comfortable using it, I had no experience in xml. Also all the code was already in place for a big part, which speeded up the whole proces a lot.

I'm very happy with the end result. It does everything I need, it's easy too use and since I made everything myself from the ground up I know exactly how every works.

Good luck with you choices.